# After updating to java 17 started to receive [error] target level should be in '1.1'...'1.8','9'...'14': 17

Tags: java, compilation, dependencies, aspectj, java-17

I updating my test framework to use Java 17, using Gradle.

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

Also upgraded Gradle to '8.0.2' version. Trying to build project received

> [error] target level should be in '1.1'...'1.8','9'...'14': 17

With some tips regarding AspectJ lib, that i dont understand (can be seen on the screenshot 1 attached).
[image: Screen 1]

So i tried also update AspectJ plugin to the latest version
`id "io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving" version "8.0.1"` in my build.gradle file. As a result AspectJ lib stopped to be seen by IDE(screenshot 2),
[image] with

> error: package org.aspectj.lang.annotation does not exist

Cant understand where to start digging and what this problem can be connected to? As a result i need to make my project work with Java 17, currently using 14 and AspectJ.

Comment: Post text rather than images, wherever practical.

Comment: Update the AspectJ compiler version to one capable of processing Java 17 code. The latest version is 1.9.19.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> [error] target level should be in '1.1'...'1.8','9'...'14'
> ```

This compiler error tells me that, according to the [AspectJ Java version compatibility matrix](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/release/JavaVersionCompatibility.html), your AspectJ compiler is limited to max. Java 14, i.e. probably somewhere in your Gradle build, you have a dependency on `org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.9.6`, where you would need at least 1.9.8. But like I said in my comment, simply go to the latest version 1.9.19. If I have some sparetime around Easter, maybe I can release 1.9.20 one of these days, but you will be fine with the current release.

Comment: thanks, it helped, also rebuilding project

Comment: Please see the valid link - [AspectJ Java version compatibility matrix](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/docs/release/JavaVersionCompatibility.adoc)

Comment: @ArturYakubenko, I updated the link to point to the new location on the Aspectj website. Next time, please edit the answer and update the link there. If you do not have enough privileges to publish the edit, another community member (e.g. I) can approve it.